# Serve a file based on request parameters in tornado

Tags: python, file, tornado

The problem looks simple but everywhere I search it I get results for uploading a file, whereas my use case is, that based on a few params, I in my Handler decide the relevant file and upload it as a link in my View. I am using `tornado` for this. e.g :

```
<div class="form-group"> <!-- Date input -->
    <label for="actDateFrom" class="control-label">Date</label>
    <input ng-model="data.actDateFrom" class="form-control" name="actDateFrom" placeholder="MM/DD/YYY" type="text"/>
</div>
<div class="form-group"> <!-- Date input -->
    <label for="actDateTo" class="control-label">Date</label>
    <input ng-model="data.actDateTo" class="form-control" name="actDateTo" placeholder="MM/DD/YYY" type="text"/>
</div>
<div class="form-group"> <!-- Submit button -->
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" data-ng-disabled="form.$invalid" data-ng-click="sendActRequest()" >Go Fetch !</button>
</div>
```

Based on the inputs above, I have a handler, that should basically filter a csv file and get that file showing up as a link .

All I am stuck at is the code for uploading that subset file as a link in my view, I can manage the rest. Please not that the file is lying somewhere on the server itself.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

Lol that was so easy, I think the funda is that only a static file can be served, I just put it in my some web/static/files path which is visible to the server and posted a href link to it, something like below:

```
<div>
                      <a href="web/static/files/activations/train.csv" name="activation logs">Activations Logs for the time period.</a> 
            </div>
```

Please dont downvote, actually I am new to Web Dev :P Thanks !